# Why do websites put an overlay of dots on their images?

Tags: website-design, images

On the following websites: https://www.the215guys.com/, https://saffronindianbistro.com/ there is a repeated pattern of black dots over the large jumbotron images.

What is the reason for the overlay of dots?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the UX question.

Comment: Can you please include an image of the effect in the question itself? The websites are very likely to change at which point your question will be much less helpful

Answer (score 6):

They are simply putting a low opacity black overlay over the images so that any light colored elements they put on top of the images (carousel arrows, white text, etc.) will stand out and not get lost in the noise.

The reason for choosing dots over a solid overlay was likely entirely a design choice because they thought it looked good.

Answer (score 3):

They are not just dots, they can be lines or a combination of gradients.

The main point, besides darkening or whitening the image is to reduce the appearance of blurrynes of a low resolution background.

The dots or pattern are not resampled, so this are seen in native resolution. This gives the ilusion you are watching an image of the native resolution of the display.